# Importing an FBX from Autodesk (Binary) is only importing Mesh Data and not Objects into scene

Tags: mesh, objects, import, .fbx

So i got a model with a very basic animation, **exported from Maya using standard game export options (which have worked before)**, but i've had some issues with random models, when importing them (fbx) **no objects are added to the "view layer"** in the "**outliner**", but also **no errors were shown in the console log**, so i went to the "Blender File" window in the "Outliner" and **the Mesh data for the imported object is there!**, so i assigned this mesh data to one random object (default cube) and it showed me the imported mesh.

This means that **the importer is in fact bringing the model but only putting the mesh data** into the blender file (green triangle icon), **not the object data** (oragne triangle icon).

I don't know if i'm missing a "must know" information for importing fbx from autodesk.

This is very important because Armatures are also a kind of "object data" for Blender that is not being imported, only the mesh data.

The object is fine because **i can open it in other very basic viewers** like the one included in windows 10.

**In this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gbK0NFcPLNutsmvRzmpdAfyIv4mLP2oq?usp=sharing) you can find a couple samples that have this error.**

**Working with Blender 3.6.2 LTS**

**How to reproduce this issue:**

- Create a new blender file
- Create a second window with the "blender file" "outliner"
- Import the provided FBX
- See the mesh data appear but no objects added to the scene

[image: As you can see the mesh data is there but no new objects were imported]

Comment: I can reproduce it with the *Plant Sample.fbx*. but the *Office Sample.fbx* has an error you have to fix `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender ....... 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 266, in elem_props_get_enum
    assert(elem_prop.props[1] == b'enum')
AssertionError` also cannot open it in https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/fbx so definitely the FBX problem. But the Plant one, yes reproducible looks like a bug, but bugs are off-topic on this site.

Comment: The error for *Office Sample.fbx* goes away if I import with *Manual Orientation* set to *Z Forward*